# Is is possible to pass a string object inside another object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a string and i would like to pass it by reference in a object.

```
var str:String = '';
var object:Object = {s:str};
object.s = 'test';
trace(str); // i would like this to output test but it is just blank
trace(object.s); //this has a value stored in it
```

Is this possible or am i thinking about this wrong?

What i am trying to do is update the str value by updating object.s. I want the sting object to be inside the object not the value of the str.

I want it to do something more like this

```
var obj2:Object = new Object();
obj2.txt = '';
var object:Object = {s:obj2};
object.s.txt = 'test';
trace(obj2.txt); // outputs test
trace(object.s.txt); //outputs test
```

Comment: You assigning blank to the `string` variable.  Where would it get any other value from?

Comment: I would like string to be set when object.s is set to 'test' i would like sting to be passed into object as the object not the value of string. so that i can update object.s and it updates string.

Comment: When you do `s: str`, `s` gets set to a copy of `str`

Comment: That is what i having problems with is there a way to have to set the object not a copy? I understand if there isn't it just seems like there should be a way. because if i pass in something like a TextInput i can set the TextInput.txt property and it will update the global textInput feild not just the local object inside object.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.  In the above example i suspect the trace works fine, but since there is no value, it does not display anything.  I don't know actionscript very well, but since it compiles down to javascript then all objects are passed by reference.  your example code actually has two objects in it one called string that is a string with no value assigned, and the other an object with a property called s that is a string.  that it why there is no output.

```
var string:String = '';
var object:Object = {s:string};
object.s = 'test';
string = object.s;
trace(string); // i would like this to output test but it is just blank
trace(object.s);
```

This should show you what you want to see, and is passed by reference, unless actionscript enforces pass by value, which i do not believe it does